# How to programmatically close ControlFX notification?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I would like to close ControlFX notification programmatically.

```
Notifications notificationBuilder = Notifications.create();
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        
        notificationBuilder.hideAfter(Duration.INDEFINITE);
        notificationBuilder.hideCloseButton();
        notificationBuilder.position(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        Parent loadedScreen = null;
        FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/notificationtest/Notification.fxml"));
        try {
            loadedScreen = (Parent) myLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NotificationTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        notificationBuilder.graphic(loadedScreen);
        notificationBuilder.show();
        //notificationBuilder.hideAfter(Duration.ZERO);
        
    });
```

There is no hide() or close() method. After showing the notification I tried to change the duration using "**notificationBuilder.hideAfter(Duration.ZERO)**" to hide the notification but it did not work.

ControlFX version: 8.40.17

Is there any way to close notification ?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/593

Answer (score 0):

This should work
notificationBuilder.hideAfter(Duration.seconds(5));